# Is there a gene that starts meiosis 2?

Tags: genetics, meiosis

Yesterday I thought about a question and asked it to my friend.  The question was
*which gene is completely the same for a male cell that made meiosis 1 recently*.

My answer was the gene that starts meiosis 2, but he said he thought that there is no such gene - only a gene to start meiosis and meiosis 1 and 2 are just parts that scientists named.

My question is is there any gene that starts meiosis 2?